# How to set daemon to kill other processes in its process group when it dies

Tags: python, linux, macos, daemon

I want to create a `Manager` daemon that spawns two subprocesses `A` and `B`. When the `Manager` daemon dies/is killed, it should kill `A` and `B`. Currently, I have it set so if I pass in `"stop"` to `Manager`, it'll send a `SIGTERM` to its Process Group, which kills everything.

However, I would like it so if I send a `SIGTERM` to `Manager` directly, it will also kill `A` and `B` as well. I've tried signal handlers, but this creates a loop where it sends `SIGTERM` to the PG, which sends it back to `Manager`, etc.

I've also tried making `Manager` a process group leader by calling `os.setpgid(os.getpid(), os.getpid())` before spawning `A` and `B` but this doesn't seem to kill `A` and `B` properly.

In the example below, running `python manager.py start` would create `Manager`, `A`, and `B`. Then:

1. `python manager.py stop` would kill all 3 processes
2. `kill -INT -$MANAGER_PGID` would kill all 3
3. `kill $MANAGER_PID` would only kill `Manager` and not `A` or `B`

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2.7

import atexit
import datetime
import os
import sys
import time
import subprocess
from signal import *


class Daemon(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.pid_file = "/var/run/manager.pid"

    def del_pid(self):
        os.remove(self.pid_file)

    def daemonize(self):
        if os.fork():
            sys.exit()
        os.chdir("/")
        os.setsid()
        os.umask(0)
        if os.fork():
            sys.exit()
        with open('/dev/null', 'r') as dev_null:
            os.dup2(dev_null.fileno(), sys.stdin.fileno())

        sys.stderr.flush()
        err = "/tmp/manager.err"
        with open(err, 'a+', 0) as stderr:
            os.dup2(stderr.fileno(), sys.stderr.fileno())

        sys.stdout.flush()
        out = "/tmp/manager.out"
        with open(out, 'a+', 0) as stdout:
            os.dup2(stdout.fileno(), sys.stdout.fileno())

        atexit.register(self.del_pid)
        pid = os.getpid()
        with open(self.pid_file, 'w+') as pid_file:
            pid_file.write('{0}'.format(pid))
        os.setpgid(pid, pid)
        # for sig in (SIGABRT, SIGTERM, SIGINT):
        #     signal(sig, self.stop)

    def get_pid_by_file(self):
        with open(self.pid_file, 'r') as pid_file:
           pid = int(pid_file.read().strip())
        return pid

    def start(self):
        self.daemonize()
        self.run()

    def stop(self, signum=None, frame=None):
        pid = self.get_pid_by_file()
        pgid = os.getpgid(pid)
        os.killpg(pgid, SIGTERM)

    def run(self):
        subprocess.Popen("a.sh", shell=True)
        subprocess.Popen("a.sh", shell=True)
        while 1:
            time.sleep(5)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    daemon = Daemon()
    if 'start' == sys.argv[1]:
        daemon.start()
    elif 'stop' == sys.argv[1]:
        daemon.stop()
```

Comment: Could you include a simplified code sample? Preferably a MCVE like described at https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Yes, it's been added now.

Comment: Why not unset the manager’s signal handler before propagating the signal to the process group?

Comment: That would probably be the way to go. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Because I create and use a PID file to find processes to stop, I stopped the loop by placing a check on whether the PID file still exists or not.